# How to automatically install updates by a desktop user

Tags: installation, updates

I want to set Ubuntu/Lubuntu [10.04] to automatically install security updates for a normal desktop user (user has no root privileges).

If I set Ubuntu/Lubuntu [10.04] to *Automatically Install Updates in the background* will it still install the security updates if the user logged in is not apart of the administrator group?

Answer (score 3):

Create a file of name, say, `local.pkla`, in the directory `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d`, whose content should be

```
[Update Manager]
Identity=unix-user:enzotib
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes
```

The text between square brackets is simply a comment, and you should substitute `enzotib` with the real username you want to give the ability to use `update-manager` without password.

To see possible `Action`s, run `pkaction`.

Reference: pklocalauthority manual page.
See also manual pages of pkaction, pkcheck, pkexec, polkit, polkitd.

Answer (score 3):

Unattended security updates are installed without the need of confirmation and without the need to be logged in as an administrator group user by choosing *"Download and install automatically"*  in *Update Manager -> Settings -> Updates* in the line *"When there are security updates"*:

#### for 12.04 LTS and later:

[image]

#### for 10.04 LTS:

[image]

Other than security updates are not installed by this. If you need to do this please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41859/howto-automatically-install-updates-desktop-user/41867#41867).